# Screen-lock: any way to specify a list of sensitive apps to opt-out locking all apps?

Tags: lock-screens

Recently I started using screen locking, just because I started using NFC and Google Wallet. If the device does not have a screen-lock set up, Google Wallet removes cards the in 5 minutes. Okay, this sounds reasonable to me for the security reasons. I don't consider all other applications super-sensitive so for me this is totally fine not to use screen locking for them. The annoying thing about the screen lock is that it locks almost everything except a more or less safe audio player with very limited capabilities like "start"/"stop"/"prev/next track": switching to another playlist requires the device to be unlocked; using a dumb calculator with zero personal data requires the device to be unlocked; opening a short-lived Firefox Focus instance requires it too.

I find the idea of locking all apps regardless their sensitiveness quite annoying, and I'm wondering is there probably a way to screen-lock only a specified list of applications ***I*** consider critical?

Currently I have a Pixel 6 Pro device with rooted stock Android 14 (not sure if I'm fine to switch to another Android-based OS, but why not?), so I guess Magisk-, XPosed/LSPosed-, XPrivacyLua-based extensions might be great in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use a `Screen Lock` or `App Lock` app.  I have used [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applockwatcher) in the past and it works well.  You can select which apps need to be locked.

Since then I have moved to [Kaspersky](https://www.kaspersky.com.au/) for its anti-virus functions.  IT comes bundled with App Lock, so I am using that.  This too works well and allows you to select the apps.

Comment: Did you have success with using these third-party lock screens along with Google Wallet (with cards not being removed by it)? I think this might not work well because Google Wallet would still expect a system level lock screen (not these third-party ones).